# SSIS package fails to run

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

sometimes 2012 SP1 SSIS package wont run. Job scheduled with sql server agent fails with

Failed to execute IS server package because of error 0x80131904. Server: xxx, Package path: xxx.dtsx, Environment reference Id: NULL.
Description: Timeout expired.

Then at the second attempt it always runs

the same package worked fine for years

the problem appeared few weeks ago

By searching internet many experience the same problem without any solution.
It's said that it's bug in sql 2012. I applied fix from

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829948

without success

- there's no other jobs running at the same time
- jobs history is reduced to 90 days instead of 365 days
- missing indexes created on SSISDB
- various timeouts set to unlimited
- msiInstaller is running daily at the same time. deactivated
- sql agent account changed from domain account to local system

after these actions the problem got worse. Now it happens daily

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a new sample package? Try looking into the All Executions report under IS Catalog, you might get some clues.

Comment: nothing in All executions cause the package didn't run.

the problem is with launching the package.

I think it's a problem of resources. Today it run correctly after adding memory to VM and setting max sql memory to 12GB instead of 6.

so free memory is now 4GB instated of 2.

I will see for few days and post solution for all those struggling with the problem

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a resource problem

problem solved when memory added to VM and sql server